# Spinner Android link to XML items file

Tags: android

I want to create a spinner in my first app, but I don't know how to link it to the item list XML file. Please help me!

UPDATE

My code :

```
<Spinner
android:width="wrap-content"
android:height="wrap-content" />
```

Comment: There are countless examples online, here's one http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Comment: Please show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Thanks @ElliotM. You could also publish that as an answer, so i can help other people by checking it as right and upvoting it

Answer (score 0):

1: Create XML file in witch you have to drag and drop spinner in your xml layout.

2: access your main xml layout in java in **oncreate** method

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

3: Create an Instance of spinner in java class.
for example

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

* R.layout.main is your xml layout where you have created spinner.

here is your **spninner**

```
 <Spinner
  android:id="@+id/spinner"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:prompt="@string/spinner_title"/>
```

And here is example if you have any problem [Spinner Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm)